# Implementing a remote fuse filesystem

Tags: python, filesystems, rpc, xml-rpc, fuse

Here is what I am trying to acheive. I have a FUSE filesystem that is running on my server. I want to be able to mount this filesystem on my client. I implemented my filesystem using python(fusepy). I have read a little about xmlrpclib which can be used for communication between the client and server. But I am quite confused if I should move around the whole filesystem from the server to the client when it is mounted or, I should just retrieve it on the go while traversing the directories. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would just retrieve whatever is needed on the go. i never used fusepy and xmlrpclib, but you could easily implement a FUSE filesystem on the client side which is accessing the serveside FUSE filesystem via RPC. The client side is just doing RPC wrapped in a FUSE class. This way you could have multiple clients simultaneously, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean moving the whole files to the client, or just the metadata? If you only need the metadata to traverse the filesystem hierarchy, I think you can download it all when it's first mounted (just compress it if there are many files/dirs), and then switch to incremental updates on client side. To read/write files is another story, maybe you can block until the whole file is uploaded/downloaded, or implement some streaming solution.